# Hadoop 2.9.0 and Hive 2.3.2 which uses Log4j-1.2.17 and log4j-core-2.6.2.jar Vulnerability Mitigation ways

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, log4j

Hadoop 2.9.0 uses log4j-1.2.17 & Hive 2.3.2 uses log4j-core-2.6.2.jar and hive-jdbc-2.3.2-standalone.jar which is vulnerable. To resolve this i went through many online resources and found various do able and non-do able solutions.

Like Upgrade Hadoop Version => Can't do at first place
directly replace log4j to newer version => Of course will not work.
reload4j => might work.
Removing vulnerable classes from log4j jar => Might Work.

My questions are..

1. Is there any known and tested solution for log4j using with i can retain this particular hadoop version and mitigate log4j vulnerabilities?
2. If I try above two might work solution. How can i test hadoop robustly, Is there any way to test all possible scenarios to ensure after changes hadoop will not fail. (I tried removing vulnerable classes way. So hadoop and Hive working fine. Except hive is showing JNDI lookup class not found WARNING. That class i removed as its vulnerable. Hive shell is working fine and executing query properly so wanted to test robustly)